# simplify square root term

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

[image]

I just wanted to know what rules were used to simplify the numerator since I thought that $1/\sqrt[3]{5}$*$\sqrt{\left(n^3\right) +\left( n\right)}$ cannot be simplified

Comment: It is like: $\sqrt[2]{...} = \sqrt[6]{(...)^3}$

Comment: ah okay because 1/2 = 3/6?

Comment: Yes that's right

Comment: Oh my god thank you very much for opening my eyes!!

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was used that

$$\sqrt{n^3+n}=\sqrt[6]{(n^3+n)^3}$$

and then factored out $n^{10}$.

Comment: I'll do that, thanks for the hint :)